# the label of my form element does not appear

Tags: html, forms, element

I have a problem with one of the element of my form the label does not appear and it sticks to another element like glue but I do not know why.
could anyone take a look PLEASE? The problem is last name

`

```
        </head>
            <body>
                <form name ="user_info" id="user_info" action="" method= "post">
                    <p>
                    <select name="addresses" id="addresses">
                    <option value="first">Mr.</option>
                    <option value="second">Mrs.</option>
                    <option value="third">Ms.</option>
                    <option value="fourth">Miss</option>
                    <option value="fifth">Dr.</option>
                    </select>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                    <label for="sex">Please select your sex</label>
                    <select name="sex" id="sex">
                    <option value="first">male</option>
                    <option value="second">female</option>
                    </p>



                    <p>
                    <label for="last_name">Last name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" size="30" maxlength="80">
                    </p>


                    <p>
                    <label for="first_name">First name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" size="30" maxlength="80">
                    </p>

                    <p>
                    <label for="email">E-Mail Address:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" maxlength="80">
                    </p>

                    <p>
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password"  size="10"     maxlength="20">   
                    </p>

                    <p>
                    <label for="interests">What are your likes?</label>
                    <select name="interests" id="interests">
                    <option value="first">Literature</option>
                    <option value="second">Programming</option>
                    <option value="third">Linguistics</option>
                    <option value="fourth">History</option>
                    <option value="fifth">Biology</option>
                    </select>
                    </p> 

                    <p>
                    <label for="newsletter">Would you like to subscribe to our newsletter?</label>
                    <select name="newsletter" id="newsletter">
                    <option value="first">Yes</option>
                    <option value="second">No</option>
                    </select>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                    <label for="user_comments">Kindly add any comment you may have here</label>
                    <textarea name="user_comments" id="user_comments" cols="40" rows="5">My default text</textarea>
                    </p>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit_button"     id="submit_button" value="Submit">

                </form>



            </body>
    </html>´
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you forgot to end your SELECT. To clarify, you need to add `</select>` after your last option:

```
<select name="sex" id="sex">
    <option value="first">male</option>
    <option value="second">female</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>
<label for="sex">Please select your sex</label>
<select name="sex" id="sex">
<option value="first">male</option>
<option value="second">female</option>
</p>
```

This is your problem. You forgot to close the select. It should look like this:

```
<p>
<label for="sex">Please select your sex</label>
<select name="sex" id="sex">
<option value="first">male</option>
<option value="second">female</option>
</select>
</p>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. unfortunately I cannot grade you above one for reasons Ido not know.

Comment: Could be you need to wait a few minutes. Doesn't matter though. Glad I could help :)